# Is it possible to export some equations from a "WYSIWYG" math editor to PHP code

Tags: php, math, equations

Writing complex equations in PHP is big deal so it would be easier if I could write them as "WYSIWYG" i.e. with MS Mathematics and export them instead of coding them. I checked out if I could use MATLAB but it can only export to C which would mean I would have to rewrite nearly everything...

If Runge-Kutta and FFM simulation is something to you, then you might understand the complexity...

An example of MS Mathematics syntax:

http://bit.ly/prXni7

gives `xi(t_(n+1))-v_xi(t_(n+1))*(DELTA_(t/2))=xi(t_n)+v_xi(t_n)*(DELTA_(t/2))`

(Errors may be in it because of the inconvenient way of copying this)

Comment: What options does MS Math offer to export equations?

Comment: It can export to word - which wont be really usefull. Rather I though of having the syntax transcoded with an engine...

Comment: For those of us who don't know MS Math, an example of syntax used would be helpful - at least to see what we're dealing with.

Comment: Just checked: export options are restricted to "low res monochrome bitmap" and "propietary XML format". It should be possible to parse `<Formula>Divide[1,Exponent[2,n]]</Formula>` into something useful but it's work to be done.

Comment: I can't see where you find those options... Are you sure you mean this software: http://bit.ly/op9FGN

Answer (score 2):

If you know LaTeX, you'll find it easier to embed complex equations using something like [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/).

WYSIWYG is overrated when it comes to math typesetting, in my opinion.  Try doing these [examples](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/tex-samples/) using MS Math and see what I mean.

Comment: that sounds good but for my calculations letting the browser do it would take hours so I need PHP so the servers does it and I can get it through ajax